# mlr3: extract variable importance for each resampling iteration

Tags: mlr3

I would like to extract variable importance for each resampling iteration with mlr3. So far, I have only found a "manual" way of doing it so I was wondering if there was a wrapper function or some other way to do it. Below is a toy example with random forest:

```
library(mlr3verse)
data("mtcars")
mtcars

task <- as_task_regr(mtcars, target = "mpg")

learner.rf <- lrn("regr.ranger", importance = "permutation", num.trees = 1000)

cv10 <- rsmp("cv", folds = 10)

resamp.rf <- resample(
  task = task, 
  learner = learner.rf, 
  resampling = cv10, 
  store_models = TRUE
)
```

Naively, I have tried the following and it does not work (that might no be surprising, I am still confused by the R6 objects):

```
resamp.rf$importance()
```

The following works but I have to do it for each resampling iteration:

```
resamp.rf$learners[[1]]$importance()
```

Or create my own extracting function:

```
aa <- resamp.rf$learners
dd  <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(aa)) {
  tmp <- data.frame(ITER = i, IMPORTANCE = aa[[i]]$importance())
  dd <- rbind(dd, tmp)
  rm(tmp)
}
```

Comment: Not sure whether this justifies a method, you can just use `Map(function(x) x$importance(), resamp.rf$learners)`, which is what the method would return as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be necessary to find the variable importance for each fold. I don't actually think it would be possible, you wouldn't do it when looking at packages like ranger or rf, you would just take the importance after training like you've done already. Also you are looking at 1 resample.

If you defined your rsmp as the following to allow more resamples:

```
cv10 <- rsmp("repeatedcv", folds = 10, repeats = 50)
```

Then maybe it would be possible to look into it for each bootstrap sample, but I would still recommend just looking at the overall result.